# Dynamic programming problem -Minimum Cost Path

Tags: c++, recursion, c++14, dynamic-programming, shortest-path

I was trying this problem - [Minimum Cost Path](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/minimum-cost-path/0/).
I have solved the problem using Dijkstra's Shortest Path Algorithm. But when i tried this using recursion+memoisation i.e. using dynamic programming, i got stuck and could not debug my code. I need help as to where my code is wrong!!

I am really glad for the help.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int n;
int a[105][105], dp[105][105];

int dfs(int x, int y){
    if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= n || y >= n){
        return INT_MAX;
    }
    if(x == 0 && y== 0){
        return a[0][0];
    }
    if(dp[x][y] != -1){
        return dp[x][y];
    }
    dp[x][y] = a[x][y] + min(dfs(x-1, y), min(dfs(x, y-1), min(dfs(x+1, y), dfs(x, y+1))));
    return dp[x][y];
}


int main(){
    int tt;
    cin >> tt;
    while(tt--){
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                cin >> a[i][j];
                dp[i][j] = -1;
            }
        }
        cout << dfs(n-1, n-1) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}



Example:
Input:
2
5
31 100 65 12 18 10 13 47 157 6 100 113 174 11 33 88 124 41 20 140 99 32 111 41 20
2
42 93 7 14

Output:
327
63
```

I am getting 2147483647 as the output for both the cases, which is the value of INT_MAX.

Comment: please put a sample input and expected output, and try to explain the problem you are encountering

Comment: You can find the sample input output at the link provided. I am getting output as the value of INT_MAX for all testcases.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] within the question without relying on external links

Comment: provided a sample in the edited post. hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The global variable `n` that `dfs` looks at is always zero (by static initialization), it's never assigned a value. When `main` calls, say, `dfs(4, 4)`, the function immediately returns `INT_MAX` due to `4 >= 0` check.

---

Once you fix this simple issue, you'll discover that your program crashes due to stack overflow. You see, `dfs(4, 4)` calls `dfs(3, 4)`, which in turn calls `dfs(4, 4)`, which calls `dfs(3, 4)`, which ...

This is not really a dynamic programming problem. It's a "shortest path in a graph" problem, suitable for, say, Dijkstra or A* algorithms.

Comment: Thank you!! that helped i tried changing static initialisation of n and learnt where i was wrong. And yes i have solved the problem using dijkstra shortest path algorithm.